# Need to create regex for analyzing rails server log

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, regex

I've a rails server log file, whose format is as follows.

```
Started <REQUEST_TYPE_1> <URL_1> for <IP_1> at <TIMESTAMP_1>
  Processing by <controller#action_1> as <REQUEST_FORMAT_1>
  Parameters: <parameters_1>
<Some logs from code>
Rendered <some_template_1> (<timetaken_1>)
Completed <RESPONSE_CODE_1> in <TIME_1>


Started <REQUEST_REQUEST_TYPE_2> <URL_2> for <IP_2> at <TIMESTAMP_2>
  Processing by <controller#action_2> as <REQUEST_FORMAT_2>
  Parameters: <parameters_2>
<Some logs from code>
Completed <RESPONSE_CODE_2> in <TIME_2>
```

Now, I need to parse this log and extract all the `REQUEST_TYPE`, `URL`, `IP`, `TIMESTAMP`, `REQUEST_FORMAT`, `RESPONSE_CODE` from above log. I'm struggling to create a good regex for it in java/ruby. `<>` is not present in actual input. I've added for readability and masking of actual data.

**Example request:**

```
Started GET "/google.com/2" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Dec 01 12:01:13 +0530 2015
  Processing by MyController#method as JS
  Parameters: {"abc" => "xyz"}
[LOG] 3 : User text log
Completed 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 3.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)


Started POST "/google.com/543" for 127.0.1.1 at Tue Dec 01 13:13:16 +0530 2015
  Processing by MyController#method_2 as JSON
  Parameters: {"efg" => "uvw"}
Completed 404 Not Authorized in 65ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
request_types = ['GET', 'POST']
urls = ['/google.com/2','/google.com/543']
ips = ['127.0.0.1','127.0.1.1']
timestamps = ['Tue Dec 01 12:01:13 +0530 2015','Tue Dec 01 13:13:16 +0530 2015']
request_formats = ['JS','JSON']
response_codes = ['200 OK','404 Not Authorized']
```

I was able to write following regex, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
request_types = /Started \w+/  //Expected array of all request types
urls = /"\/.*\/"/ //Expected array of all urls types
ips = /"d{1,3}.d{1,3}.d{1,3}.d{1,3}"/ //Expected array of all ips types
timestamps =  /at \w+/
request_formats =/as \w+/
response_codes = /Completed \w+/
```

I hope to get some help in creating regex for extracting this parameters from given input in JAVA/RUBY. I would prefer java, if possible.

Comment: Does your original log file have these brackets as well (`<>`) ?

Comment: Nope. It was just to mask actual data

Comment: Something like https://regex101.com/r/uI6oV1/3 ?

Comment: Yup, But the lines which says `parameters`, `some log`, needn't be present always. Also, how will I use that in JAVA/ruby?

Comment: @Jan Added sample input with masked data and expected output.

Comment: You can use [`^Started\s+(?<request_type>\S+)\s+"(?<url>\S+)"\s+for\s+(?<ip>\d+(?:\.\d+)+)\s+at\s+(?<tsp>[a-zA-Z]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+\s+\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+\s+\+\d+\s\d{4})\s+(?:Processing\s+by\s+\S+)\s+as\s+(?<request_format>\S+)(?:\s+Parameters:\s+\S+)?(?:(?:(?:(?!\nStarted ).)*Completed\s)(?<response_code>\d+(?:(?!\sin\s).)*))?`](https://regex101.com/r/mJ3pP8/2). If it works alright (please test with your input), I will show how to use it in Java.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew checked on regex101, it says no matched found.

Comment: What string does it say no match found with?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew None of them matched. Here you go https://regex101.com/r/iN7yO3/1

Comment: [It works alright](https://regex101.com/r/iN7yO3/2), you must have changed the pattern when copying/pasting. When you copy paste the text from SO comments, the line breaks are kept with invisible characters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oops.. Not sure, how can I make mistake in copy-paste. Anyways, it works great! Can you share how to use this in JAVA?

Comment: There are gems that will parse your log for you if you're interested in saving time.

Comment: @MarsAtomic which gem?

Comment: @Abhishek Practicing your [search fu](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=log+analyzer) pays off.

Comment: @MarsAtomic got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Java snippet showing how to get the details from the log into separate array lists in Java:

```
String re = "(?sm)^Started\\s+(?<requesttype>\\S+)\\s+\"(?<url>\\S+)\"\\s+for\\s+(?<ip>\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)+)\\s+at\\s+(?<tsp>[a-zA-Z]+\\s+[a-zA-Z]+\\s+\\d+\\s+\\d+:\\d+:\\d+\\s+\\+\\d+\\s\\d{4})\\s+(?:Processing\\s+by\\s+\\S+)\\s+as\\s+(?<requestformat>\\S+)(?:\\s+Parameters:\\s+\\S+)?(?:(?:(?:(?!\nStarted ).)*Completed\\s)(?<responsecode>\\d+(?:(?!\\sin\\s).)*))?";
String str = "Started GET \"/google.com/2\" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Dec 01 12:01:13 +0530 2015\n  Processing by MyController#method as JS\n  Parameters: {\"abc\" => \"xyz\"}\n[LOG] 3 : User text log\nCompleted 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 3.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)\n\n\nStarted POST \"/google.com/543\" for 127.0.1.1 at Tue Dec 01 13:13:16 +0530 2015\n  Processing by MyController#method_2 as JSON\n  Parameters: {\"efg\" => \"uvw\"}\nCompleted 404 Not Authorized in 65ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(re);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
List<String> requesttypes = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> ips = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> timestamps = new ArrayList<String>(); 
List<String> requestformats = new ArrayList<String>(); 
List<String> responsecodes = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()){
    requesttypes.add(matcher.group("requesttype"));
    urls.add(matcher.group("url"));
    ips.add(matcher.group("ip"));
    timestamps.add(matcher.group("tsp"));
    requestformats.add(matcher.group("requestformat"));
    responsecodes.add(matcher.group("responsecode"));
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
    System.out.println(matcher.group("requesttype"));
    System.out.println(matcher.group("url")); 
    System.out.println(matcher.group("ip")); 
    System.out.println(matcher.group("tsp")); 
    System.out.println(matcher.group("requestformat")); 
    System.out.println(matcher.group("responsecode")); 
}
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/xFwi4s). You can even print the arrays after you get the matching done with, e.g. `System.out.println(urls)`:

```
System.out.println(requesttypes);
System.out.println(urls);
System.out.println(ips);
System.out.println(urls);
System.out.println(timestamps);
System.out.println(requestformats);
System.out.println(responsecodes);
```

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/Ift94B). The output is:

```
[GET, POST]
[/google.com/2, /google.com/543]
[127.0.0.1, 127.0.1.1]
[/google.com/2, /google.com/543]
[Tue Dec 01 12:01:13 +0530 2015, Tue Dec 01 13:13:16 +0530 2015]
[JS, JSON]
[200 OK, 404 Not Authorized]
```

The regex matches:

- `(?sm)^` - start of a line (due to `^` and `?m` option)
- `Started\\s+` - literal `Started` string and 1+ whitespaces
- `(?<requesttype>\\S+)` - Group "request type" holding 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `\\s+\"` - 1+ whitespace followed with `"`
- `(?<url>\\S+)` - Group "url" holding 1+ non-whitespace
- `\"\\s+for\\s+` - `"` followed with 1+ whitespace + `for` + 1+ whitespace
- `(?<ip>\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)+)` - IP group containing digits + `.` + digits (`.`+digits 1+ times)
- `\\s+at\\s+` - the word `at` surrounded with whitespace
- `(?<tsp>[a-zA-Z]+\\s+[a-zA-Z]+\\s+\\d+\\s+\\d+:\\d+:\\d+\\s+\\+\\d+\\s\\d{4})` - timestamp group holding letter and digits in different order separated with whitespace acc. to the input examples

  - `\\s+` - 1+ whitespace
- `(?:Processing\\s+by\\s+\\S+)\\s+as\\s+` - `Processing by` followed with some word (1+ non-whitespaces) followed with the word `as` surrounded with whitespace
- `(?<requestformat>\\S+)` - Group "request format" that consists of non-whitespace symbols
- `(?:\\s+Parameters:\\s+\\S+)?` - optional group `Paramters:` followed with whitepspace(s) and some word
- `(?:(?:(?:(?!\nStarted ).)*Completed\\s)(?<responsecode>\\d+(?:(?!\\sin\\s).)*))?` - an optional group (since enclosed in `(?:...)?`) that matches any characters up to `Completed`, but that has no `Started`  (due to the tempered greedy token `(?:(?!\nStarted ).)*`), and then matches `Completed` followed with a whitespace, and then `(?<responsecode>\\d+(?:(?!\\sin\\s).)*)` matches and captures into Group "response code" digits followed with any characters up to the whole word `in` surrounded with spaces.

Comment: Nice. Can you share a bit more on how did you construct this regex? I mean, How to understand this regex?

Comment: Let's say I don't want time stamp. So, I removed `(?<tsp>[a-zA-Z]+\\s+[a-zA-Z]+\\s+\\d+\\s+\\d+:\\d+:\\d+\\s+\\+\\d+\\s\\d{4})` from the regex and it says no match :|. https://regex101.com/r/iN7yO3/3 . How is that possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot just remove it. Make it optional by enclosing with `(?:` and `)?`.

Comment: Awesome!! I'll have to learn more about regex, so that I can do this next time by myself! Thanks :)